# Template not loading in a Backbone.js app - built using Yeoman

Tags: backbone.js, yeoman

I am using an .ejs template in my view. But for some reason the view does not load the given template. It returns undefined. Here's the code:

```
sandplate2.applicationView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: 'div',

  template: _.template($("appl.ejs").html()),

  initialize: function(){
    console.log("Application view initialize");

    _.bindAll(this, "render");

    this.render();
  },

  render: function(){
    console.log("Application view rendering");
    this.$el.html(this.template());
    return this;
  }
});
```

Do I have to configure something else in order to load a template?

I structured my app using Yeoman. I used the init and backbone generators.

FYI - The template I am trying to load is loaded in the index.html using a script element.

Answer (score 2):

If you built it using Yeoman, take a look at app.js to see if you are using [Backbone.LayoutManager](https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager).  You might have to change the configuration there for EJS to work. By default, I think it should be expecting [Underscore](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template) templates.

I'm using [Handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/) and I updated my app.js to look like this:

```
Backbone.LayoutManager.configure({
  manage: true,

  paths: {
    layout: "templates/layouts/",
    template: "templates/"
  },

  fetch: function(path) {
    path = path + ".html";

    if (!JST[path]) {
      $.ajax({ url: app.root + path, async: false }).then(function(contents) {
        JST[path] = Handlebars.compile(contents);
      });
    }

    return JST[path];
  }
});
```

I also added Handlebars to the module's define() call, passing in 'Handlebars' as a reference.  You might need to do something similar for EJS.

Comment: awesome. Will try this tonight.

Comment: BTW how did you install handlebars? Do you have a sample I could look at? I ran yeoman install handlebars and it doesn't install it in my project anywhere.

Comment: I dropped an AMD version of Handlebars (because I'm using RequireJS) into the scripts/libs folder, added a handlebars entry to config.js 'paths' section and then edited the Backbone.LayoutManager.configure() like I mentioned above.

Comment: I generated my project using yeoman init backbone and therefore don't have app.js. Is there anyway I could include the above backbone.layoutmanager code in the main.js. If you could show an example would be immensely helpful. thanks.

Comment: Create a new project in a temp folder by running yeoman init bbb.  This will create the app.js file for you to look at.  However, this method uses require.js so there will be extra stuff, similar to my app.js file.

Comment: The problem with bbb generator is it does not copy components directory into the app folder. When I run yeoman install handlebars it ends up crashing with a FATAL error. However, the components directory with handlebars is successfully created in the root of the project but doesn't go into the app dir. So, that's why I was trying to work with backbone generator. Since you are using bbb, I'm just curious to know if you are manually copying handlebars into the app folder?

Comment: Yes, I unfortunately had to install Handlebars manually with an AMD wrapped version of Handlebars.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with latest [backbone genearator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone) with yeoman 1.0beta.
We have made lot of improvements on it including [Precompiling ejs templates](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/pull/20). You don't want to worry about templates, yeoman will precompile and load it for you.

A sample generated code for input-view is provided below.

```
Todo.Views.InputView = Backbone.View.extend({

    template: JST['app/scripts/templates/input.ejs'],

    render: function(){
       $(this.el).html(this.template());
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Conventions aside, it looks like the problem is simply your jQuery lookup.

```
_.template($("appl.ejs")...
```

`$('appl.ejs')` isn't a valid DOM selector unless you have an element like this in your index.html

```
<appl class="ejs"></appl>
```

If you're trying to target your template with jQuery, give it an ID or something that jQuery can find like so:

```
<script type="text/template" id="appl">
    <div></div><!-- template html here -->
</script>

    // later...
    $('#appl').html()
    // will get your template html
```

However, as others have mentioned, in a yeoman and require.js workflow, you can ask require.js to fetch the template for you as text and throw it around as a variable before creating an underscore template.