# Yeoman/Grunt does not automatically compile EJS templates with the Backbone generator?

Tags: backbone.js, generator, yeoman

I tried to externalize my Underscore templates in files. Found that using yeoman was a good way to achieve this. I tried to make it works with this code (test.ejs only contains text) :

```
var test = JST['app/scripts/templates/test.ejs'];
console.log(test());
```

test() return undefined. I read [Template not loading in a Backbone.js app - built using Yeoman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557699/template-not-loading-in-a-backbone-js-app-built-using-yeoman) and https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/pull/20 especially. But it wasn't help, test() was still undefined.

Finally I read https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-jst and tried to run : grun jst which works very well. But I have to run this task each time I edit my templates. I not very used to Grunt but found in Gruntfile.js that it should watch *.ejs files in the templates folder and then run the jst task but it does not work. Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please share your `Gruntfile.js` generated by yeoman. Are you sure you are running `grunt server`??

Comment: Ok now it works when i'm running `grunt server`. This just makes sense. Thanks @RSK

Answer (score 1):

You could use https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch

```
watch: {
  scripts: {
    files: ['templates/*.ejs'],
    tasks: ['grunt-contrib-jst']
  },
},
```